# Batch for removing last 2 pages from PDF files on a folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, pdftk

I am using the [PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) to remove last 2 pages of a bunch of PDF from a specific folder.

For removing it individually on a file, this code works perfectly fine as the last two pages are removed from original.pdf and a newly created reduced.pdf copy is created without the last two pages

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin"
start pdftk.exe C:\Desktop\long\original.pdf cat 1-r3 output C:\Desktop\short\reduced.pdf

pause
```

Fyi, the pdf files all have various alphanumeric filenames and a **-** as separator between filename words e.g. the-march-event-2022.pdf

What I need now is how to automate is so the script would go through each pdf file on the **long**  folder and create a new copy with identical filename through the command into the **short** folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task can be done with a batch file with only following single command line:

```
@for %%I in ("C:\Desktop\long\*.pdf") do @"C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe" "%%I" cat 1-r3 output "C:\Desktop\short\%%~nxI" && echo Successfully processed "%%~nxI" || echo ERROR: Failed to process "%%~nxI"
```

This command line uses the Windows command **FOR** to process all PDF files in the specified folder. For each PDF file is executed *pdftk* with the fully qualified file name of the current PDF file as input file name and the file name + extension with a different directory path as output file name. Run `for /?` in a command prompt window for help on this command.

There is output the success message on `pdftk.exe` exits with value `0`. Otherwise the error message is output on `pdftk.exe` exits with value not equal `0`.

The two `@` are for suppressing the output of the **FOR** command line and of each executed *pdftk* command line on processing the PDF files in the specified folder.

Please see [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of the conditional operators `&&` and `||`.